# Executing PHP if a link is clicked

Tags: php, html, database

I've been searching around the internet, and of course Stackoverflow for answers on how to execute a PHP command when a link is clicked.  Here is some basic code I have that's trying to either 'Update' or 'Delete' the data within the form.

```
if(isset($_GET['Delete'])){

                $sql = "DELETE FROM addresses WHERE id ='$_POST[id]'";
                mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                header("Location: form.php");
            };

    if (isset($_GET['update'])){
                $sql = "UPDATE addresses SET firstname='$_POST[firstname]', lastname='$_POST[lastname]', age='$_POST[age]' WHERE id='$_POST[id]'";
                mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                header("Location: form.php");
            };




?>
```

---

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retreve, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    echo "<form action=form.php method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=firstname value={$row['firstname']}> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=lastname value={$row['lastname']}> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=age value={$row['age']}> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type=hidden name=id value={$row['id']}> </td>";
    //links insead of buttons
    echo "<td><a href = # id='update'> Update</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href = # id='delete'> Delete</a> </td>";

}
```

I have above the functions I'm trying to call whenever I click the links "Update" and "Delete".  What am I suppose to do in order to get the PHP to execute.

NOTE: The database connection is not shown but it is connected.

Comment: `echo "<td><a href="?update=1" id='update'> Update</a></td>";` <- just set update in to query string to any value ?!

Comment: It's not working.  And this is basically a bunch of different first names, lastnames, age, all in a nice table.  But what am I suppose to do in order for the PHP to be executed on a specific entry.

Comment: form method is post, you will never  execute  that `if statment`

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: mixing forms with urls - did you wnat a submit button?

Comment: It's something I'm doing for a class and my teacher wanted links instead of buttons.  It worked perfect with buttons but he insists on links.

Comment: so the link has to have the data required, you cant use form elements at all

Comment: How would I go about using the data instead of forms?

Comment: @Matt answered below, you should be able to add the update yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td><a href = 'form.php?type=delete&id=99' id='delete'> Delete</a> </td>";
```

`{$row['id']}` for 99 in your particular case
then:

```
if($_GET['type']=='delete'){

                    $sql = "DELETE FROM addresses WHERE id ='$_GET[id]'";
                    mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                    header("Location: form.php");
}elseif ($_GET['type']=='update'){

//

}
```

Comment: The new if statement makes the page just go blank.

Comment: at top of page add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Error reporting "Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/ubuntu/workspace/form.php on line 22 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/ubuntu/workspace/form.php on line 25 "

Comment: Which doesn't make sense since the data is being taken from the database.

Comment: sigh the crazy js brigade have arrived - all they own is a hammer - good luck with them

Answer (score -1):

if you are using the same form then check for your form method.Your form method is post an your conditions contains `$_GET['Delete']` change it to `$_POST['Delete']`

Comment: I did notice that and I did change them. Thanks though.

Comment: @Matt you may know this ,, its a suggestion, you can use form submit buttons instead of  `<a href = # id='update'> Update</a>` OR use `onClick="$(this).submit()"` and if submiting on the page use `PHP_SELF`

Comment: I used buttons with some old code I had and it worked perfectly.  It's just the assignment I'm doing, my teacher didn't like that I used buttons and wanted me to do it using links instead.  That's when I ran into problems.  But thanks for the idea.